# About java class and constructor

Tags: java, class

I have a problem with this code

```
public class JavaApplication٣ {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Rectangels vo = new Rectangels(4,40);
        Rectangels vs = new Rectangels(3.5,35.9);
          printing(vo);
          printing(vs);
          

    }
```

//the problem in this part the GetArea and GetPara can't reach the Rectangels class

```
static void printing(Rectangels val){
    System.out.println("rectangel AREA :"+val.GetArea);
        System.out.println("rectangel PARA :"+val.GetPara);

    
    }
}
```

//the problem in this part the GetArea and GetPara can't reach the Rectangels class in NetBeans shows me "cannot find symbol"

```
    class Rectangels{
    double width=1;
    double height=1;

         Rectangels(){
             
        }
       Rectangels(double w , double h){
             width=w;
             height=h;
        }
       double GetArea(){
       return width*height;
       }
           double GetPara(){
       return 2*(width+height);
       }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is syntax error in your printing method, the method calls that obtain area and parameter from the rectangles instance should be followed by () as shown:

```
static void printing(Rectangels val){
    System.out.println("rectangel AREA :"+val.GetArea());
        System.out.println("rectangel PARA :"+val.GetPara());

    
    }
}
```

You can check the following link for more details https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods.asp